# ReactRouter: Pass data/object in <Link>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm fairly new to React and ReactRouter. I've got basic routing down, and am now trying to pass an object from one component to a sibling component using Link.

I've spent hours and hours here on SO, and viewing other tutorials, but none of the code I've tried works. I either get an error on the receiving component, or no errors, but then the data I'm supposedly sending is undefined. I have a feeling I'm missing something very basic.

Can someone either post a very simple working example of sending an object via Link, and using that data in a sibling component? Or, point to an existing working example on StackBlitz or something similar?

I'm using functional components, React v. 16.13.1, and react-router-dom v. 5.2.0 (version taken from package.json).

Thanks in advance for any and all help!

Comment: Why not just pass the data object through the `context` rather than trying to use the router.

Comment: I've heard of the context API and the useContext hook, but haven't learned how to use them yet. The question was posted specifically about passing data between sibling components using Link, not just general methods of sharing data. The partial code examples I've seen using Link look simple, so I know I must be missing something.  That's why I'm interested in a complete, simple working example.

Comment: The object is a routing object, not necessarily a data object. Take a look at the documentation for React router on using an object with Link: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link/to-object

Comment: The URL you provided was my starting point. I think my Link syntax was correct: state: {foo: "bar"}. But I was never able to resolve 'foo' in the receiving component. Tried using this.state.foo, this.props.foo, this.props.state.foo, etc. I either got errors, or no errors but then 'foo' was undefined.

Comment: You could also use the state object to pass data from one route to another. Can you however provide some code of what you've tried so far and what is your setup basically, so we can be of more use.

Comment: @Daniel: Yep, the state object ended up working for me. It was a bit tricky to figure out the correct syntax to access it in the second component. See my second comment to the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for you:

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
  useLocation
} from "react-router-dom";
```

Navigating from Sibling1 to Sibling2:

```
<Link to={{pathname: "/path_of_sibling2", state: "this data would be sent" }}>Sibling 2</Link>
```

Or you can pragmatically push like:

```
history.push({pathname: "/path_of_sibling2", state: "this data would be sent" });
```

Now in Sibling 2, you can recover this state like this:

```
const {state} = useLocation();

return (
  <p>{state}</p>
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but it only works for a string, not for an object. The question was specifically about sending data in an object with Link. I tried "state: {message:"this data would be sent"}" in the Sibling 1. Then I tried using "state.message" in Sibling 2, and got the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined". Simply referencing "state" didn't cause errors, but only resolved to "undefined" Would you please post another example, of sending an object in Sibling 1 with Link, and then accessing that data in Sibling 2?

Comment: OK, did some more research, and this seems to work. In Sibling 1:  "return <Link to={{pathname: "/TestB", state: { foo: "BAR" } }}>Test B</Link>" In Sibling 2: "const location = useLocation();  const someVar = location.state?.foo;"... and, it WORKS! Yippee. I've spent an insane amount of time on this today.

Comment: Follow up question: What does the question mark in "location.state?.foo" do? I've never seen that syntax before?

Comment: Answering my own follow up question: "?." is the Optional Chaining operator. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining Not quite sure why that's needed here to make the reference to 'state' work, but it is.

Comment: Hey @JS_Newbie, I was offline earlier. Good to see that you saw it through. Let me know if you have any other questions. Also consider accepting my answer

Comment: Would you please post an example using an object in Sibling 1, and reading it in Sibling 2? That would answer he original question, and I would gladly accept that answer. Even though I discovered one approach (see code in comment #2), I'd be interested in seeing how you do it.

Comment: @JS_Newbie our answers are the same. Instead of string you've passed an object. My example passing an object would be similar as #2 comment (just a bit cleaner).